# highlight an imageview on gridview when long press select

Tags: android, gridview, baseadapter

I have a gridview that shows a list of images, and I implemented choice mode listener for this gridview. The problem is, when I press long click to select set of images, they are not highlighted..

item_photo.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/photo"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/media_thumbnail"/>
```

fragment_photos.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- Empty View -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/empty_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="gone">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/download_arrow"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:contentDescription="@string/downloads"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_photo"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/download_arrow"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/no_media"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <!-- Photos List -->
    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
        android:numColumns="3"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:choiceMode="multipleChoiceModal"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

PhotosFragment.java

```
public class PhotosFragment extends Fragment
{
    @Bind (R.id.list)
    GridView mGridView;

    private MediaGridAdapter mAdapter;
    private ArrayList<File> mFiles;


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_media, container, false);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, view);

        mGridView.setMultiChoiceModeListener(new MultiChoiceModeListener());

        // set adapter and fetch files code ....

        return view;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no magic highlight effect, you have to implement it yourself, example would be setting a foreground drawable which is a semi transparent gray.

Comment: I have tried to add listSelector, and many solutions but none of them worked

Comment: add those failed attempt to your post as edit, you cut too much information, it would not help